# How to select multiple text nodes as a single string using xpath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am pretty new to xpath and I am trying to scrape a website using xpath expression in scrapy.
The structure of the page that I am trying to scrape is-

```
...
<div class="article-body">
<p class="body">Text1</p>
<p class="body">Text2</p>
<p class="body">Text3</p>
...
```

The xpath that I am trying is-

```
//div[@class="article-body"]/p/text()
```

But all I get is `Text1` in my database. Instead of this, I want the output as-

```
Text1.Text2.Text3
```

I think I should use `concat` or `string-join` or some function like that. But I am unable to work it out. Since I have to pass this xpath expression as an argument in scrapy, I need to have it as a single expression only.

I tried feeding the `concat` function into my django-scraper as-

```
concat(//div[@class="article-body"]/p)
```

But it threw this error at me-

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\unified.py", line 100, in xpath raise ValueError(msg if six.PY3 else msg.encode("unicode_escape"))
```

I got this same error when I tried (there is no other `<p>` element on the page)-

```
concat(//p)
```

or

```
string-join(//p)
```

However, when I am trying, `string(//p)` I am getting `Text1` in my database.

Comment: there is no `concat` in Python. Shubham Jain shows (probably) Java code. You could use  `".".join(list_with_text_elements)` if you have list with text elements - or `for` loop if you need to convert elements to text.

Comment: @furas Actually I am looking for xpath expression to do the joining part while the data is being fed to the crawler. That will save me from the 'later-on' database tampering to cleanse the data.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this :-

```
concat(//div[@class="article-body"]/p)

String values = myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("concat(//div[@class="article-body"]/p)"));
```

OR

You need to do something like this

```
    ArrayList<String> name;
    String name1;
    List<WebElement> options = myTestDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class="article-body"]/p"));
    System.out.println(options.size());
    for(int i=0 ; i<options.size() ; i++){
        System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
        name1 = options.get(i).getText();
        name.add(name1);
    }
```

Now you can perform concatination